# how to resolve the issue of Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, gradlew

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter project on Debian, specifically with the Gradle build process. When attempting to run flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle, I encounter the following error:

````
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain```

i just download my flutter and android studio on debien OS (linux) and when ever i create a project i face this problem 



i downloaded gradle and nothing change i just don't know what to do please help me
````

Answer (score 0):

Run this command. This will cleanup build files.

```
flutter clean
```

Then run. This will rebuild gradle files.

```
gradle wrapper
```

Launch android studio and chek sdk is properly install or not.

If above doesn't work reinstall android studio